# findall as a stop criterion in loop

Tags: python, findall

I am trying to create a loop which depends on a findall results. My loop each time takes a text searches for the pattern and if it finds it is doing some staff. The last time it searches and finds nothing it gives me an error:

```
cursor = re.findall(r'MDpub\w+[^\"]', f)[0] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My python code is as follows

```
cursor = re.findall(r'MDpub\w+[^\"]', f)[0]     
while cursor:
    next_url = 'url'
    subId = subId+1
    wget = "wget command"
    os.system(wget)
    f = open(('name of file')       
    if (re.findall(r'MDpub\w+[^\"]', f) != cursor):
        cursor = re.findall(r'MDpub\w+[^\"]', f)[0] 
        print cursor
```

Comment: If you're expecting the last `.findall` to fail, have you considered using a `try` / `except` statement?

Comment: Why do you use `findall()` if you only take the first result?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, stupid of me, not to do so, @sapi